# php exceeds execution time on throwing an exception in recursion

Tags: php, exception, recursion, runtime-error, xdebug

Edit: rewrote from scratch, the old question wasn't useful

I've got an error occuring after throwing an exception inside recursion.
The exception is not caught anywhere, it should just pop up and show `uncaught exception error`, which it doesn't. Instead, it produces `time limit hit` kind of error. If I put var_dumps in my code, it looks like the exception is thrown, but then it just freezes and fails after it exceeds limit.

this is part of the recursive function:

```
if($this->prvky[$iA]->ini < 1 || $this->prvky[$iB]->ini < 1){
    echo '--- THROWING ---';
    throw new \OutOfBoundsException('ini is smaller than 1');
}
```

It runs very fine in tests, exception can be thrown and if it is, it successfully fails on `uncaught exception`.

In runs fine in real world when no exception is thrown.

But when condition passes in real world and exception is thrown, `--- THROWING ---` gets printed, which should be followed by `uncaught exception`, but instead it spins off crazy and fails after a while, producing `time limit exceeded` error. I know for sure that the exception is thrown and I know for sure that I'm not catching the exception anywhere.

Comment: Can you add more code? Not easy to understand what's going on in the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem was combination of `out of memory` error that sadly **didn't show up**, insane settings in xdebug and object connectedness producing lot of data.

Out of memory happened because the exception kept track of all values passed to functions, thanks to this insane settings:

```
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

which I put in my xdebug long time ago and forgot about.
So those objects that have references to other objects and so on, the whole structure (lots of long configs) got stored in the stack repeatedly on each call. I though this should be handled only by xdebug, but it seems like once an exception is thrown, xdebug adds this info to exception's copy of stack thus consuming lot of memory. (probably, just my explanation)

But it printed `out of time` instead of `out of memory`. According to logs, **both** errors *(2 fatal errors in the same request)* happened one after the other, but only the second one was printed. The data from stack was really long, so it exceeded time when trying to write the stack in logs, long after the memory limit was hit, producing second error, that got printed instead of the first one.