# laravel controller not returning value after insertion

Tags: laravel-4, controller, return-value

When i comment the inserting query, the return works.but with the query return is not working.it would be great if anyone can help immediatly

---

```
 public function regCustomer()
{
    $arr = [];

    $cus_name = Input::get('cusname');
    $cus_address = Input::get( 'address' );
    $cus_phone = Input::get( 'phone' );
    $cus_email = Input::get( 'email' );

    try{
        DB::table('Customers')->insert(
            array(
                'customer_name' => $cus_name,
                'address' => $cus_address,
                'phone' => $cus_phone,
                'email' => $cus_email
                )
        );

       return 1;

    }catch(Exception $ex){
        return '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 - Cannot catch database exception in seed or migration class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576314/laravel-4-cannot-catch-database-exception-in-seed-or-migration-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the catch block parameter to match this:

```
catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
```